# Con dos arreglos, almacenar matricula y edad, despues mostrar los valores menor y mayor del arreglo edad

Tags: c

El problema es que cuando lo corro, la edad menor me muestra la edad y matricula 0, pero el mayor si me muestra el resultado correcto lo cual no entiendo porque los dos son identicos. ayudaaa

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 5
int main(){
int i, indicemenor, indicemayor, matricula[TAM], edad[TAM], cont;
for(i=0;i<TAM;i++){
    printf("Dime cual es tu matricula: ");
    scanf("%d",&matricula[i]);
    printf("Dime tu edad alumno %d: ",matricula[i]);
    scanf("%d",&edad[i]);
}
indicemenor = 0;
indicemayor = 0;
for(i=1;i<TAM;i++){
    if(edad[indicemenor] > edad[i]){
        indicemenor = i;
    }
    else if(edad[indicemayor] < edad[i]){
        indicemayor = i;
    }
}
printf("El alumno menor tiene %d a%cos y tiene la matricula: %d",edad[indicemenor], -92, 
matricula[indicemenor]);
printf("\nEl alumno mayor tiene %d a%cos y tiene la matricula: %d",edad[indicemayor], 
-92, matricula[indicemayor]);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: No veo ningún problema https://tio.run/##nZJLTsMwEIb3PsWoVVGqBtTnhqSVkGDJjh1kYdkOjOQ4KHEWFcqhOAMHCxMnad0HG7Kw7Jnx98/8jrh9F6JpxmiErqSCuLQS87uPHRtLlaJR8PLwDBuGxkLG0QTTL7fHENBIFCpTJi8OB75vDxm3BYpK81e6nISgJJf9VuTGRizNiwC38whjikY4mxEV6PssiJ0Go0fMFIiKa1Al2OoIvIfRNHKlpeCGKidyFN4c9TDp0yckIrQtANdVZnKYSMKEVy75TNezy9TMmxS2MI@YN20X6AZaXAyEadCBjoQEdjDAuyJXeCKBXT@1W5Uu1TmoVU4g/hvUt3YA1Wxw5EkPPnRqFhW98oTc@fnOS9j3Ac1911tLLgYJgXkmegkybVB7M56ea@pfem7ea3ouQXqsULYqTPsWrG6aBSzYEpZsBSu2hjXb0C/8Cw